# Having trouble retaining a CGPath object (warning appears)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have an instance variable `CGMutablePathRef _mutablePath` which I set as `@property (nonatomic) CGMutablePathRef mutablePath;` . I override the setter method:

```
- (void) setMutablePath:(CGMutablePathRef)mutablePath
{
    if (_mutablePath)
    {
        CGPathRelease(_mutablePath);
        _mutablePath = NULL;
    }

    _mutablePath = CGPathRetain(mutablePath);
}
```

However I am getting a warning on this line: `_mutablePath = CGPathRetain(mutablePath);` that says:

```
Assigning to 'CGMutablePathRef' (aka 'struct CGPath *') from 'CGPathRef' (aka 'const struct CGPath *') discards qualifiers
```

Why would this not work? This seems to work with CT (core text) objects when I do it. I've tried a bunch of different casts but can't get the error to go away, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: While not directly related to the question, you should protect against the situation where `mutablePath == _mutablePath` because you release before you retain.

Comment: Thanks will do this. So ultimately this is to protect against wasting time if mutable path already equals _mutablepath? Or is there another side effect that could occur (I'm not seeing it if so).

Comment: No, not just for performance. When you call release, if your object is the only one holding a reference to the path it will be deallocated. So by the time you call retain it will be invalid/deallocated. You can get around this by calling retain before you release, or explicitly checking for equality.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would that look if you called retain before release? That probably would be better code than checking the equality wouldn't it?

Comment: I've seen it done both ways, I guess it's a matter of personal taste. Here's the retain before release one. `CGMutablePathRef tmp = (CGMutablePathRef)CGPathRetain(mutablePath); if(_mutablePath) { CGPathRelease(_mutablePath); _mutablePath = NULL; } _mutablePath = tmp;`

Comment: @idz: The `tmp` is unnecessary, since `CGPathRetain()` must return its input parameter. You can just say `CGPathRetain(mutablePath); CGPathRelease(_mutablePath); _mutablePath = mutablePath;`, with no conditionals at all.

Comment: @KevinBallard Thanks, wasn't 100% sure so decided to code it defensively! Much neater without the clutter.

Comment: Believe you still need the if (_mutablePath) because with CoreGraphics you can't release a NULL object? @kevinballard

Comment: @CoDEFRo: Read the docs. `CGPathRetain(foo)` is identical to `if (foo) CFRetain(foo); return foo`. It does the `NULL`-test for you. And `CGPathRelease()` is the equivalent for `CFRelease()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CGPathRetain()` is declared as

```
CGPathRef CGPathRetain(CGPathRef path);
```

This means it returns a `CGPathRef` instead of a `CGMutablePathRef`. You should cast the result back to `CGMutablePathRef` before assigning it to your `_mutablePath` ivar.

Comment: Thanks. I kept doing the casting inside of the CGPathRetain call instead of outside of it, stupid error on my part.